# Using variables as parameters in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make a vending machine logic using Prolog (amzi) but it is very difficult to handle parameters. So far I have this:

```
drink(soda,1).
drink(coffee,4).
drink(tea,3).
drink(mango,7).
drink(apple,5).

machine:-
   write('choose a drink: pepsi, coffee, tea, mango'),
   nl,
   read(X),
   nl,
   drink(X,C).
```

the output that I am getting is:

```
?- machine.
choose a drink: pepsi, coffee, tea, mango
mango.

yes
```

I want to get the price of the drink after I type the drink name, any tips on how I can handle this?

p.s. it is not logical do something like machine(X,Y) and type the name of the drink in the beginning of the query because the customer should see the list then choose a drink.

Comment: You just ahve to write it out. After the user entered `mango` and you did a `read` you haven't done any more `write`s. So after `drink(X, C)`, just do, `write('Cost of '), write(X), write(' is '), write(C), nl.`. Or use the `format` command (you can look it up).

Comment: thanks a lot, the problem is solved.